# Need to remove only character which are at the end

Tags: oracle

Need to remove only characters at the end.

1. 2014JP34343DD
2. 2013GH43422

Output:

1. 2014JP34343
2. 2013GH43422

Tried regexp fuctions and even simple substr and instr function but not able to remove it.

Comment: Which programming language? It's oracle sql?

Comment: Yes, I am using oracle sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regexp_replace seems to be a simple option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2014JP34343DD' from dual union all
  3     select '2013GH43422'   from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6         regexp_replace(col, '[[:alpha:]]+$') result
  7  from test;

COL           RESULT
------------- -------------
2014JP34343DD 2014JP34343
2013GH43422   2013GH43422

SQL>
```